# Data not displaying when I loop through with Django Template Tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm pretty stumped. When I go to loop through each "Service", nothing shows in the browser.
I've checked to make sure the data I've entered through the admin area is actually in the database (Postgres), and it is. Maybe i have a syntax issue somewhere?

**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models

    class Service(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      service_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
      is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

      def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from corpus_christi.models import Service, Member, Area

    def corpuschristi(request):
      services = Service.objects.all()
      context = {
        'services': services
      }
     return render(request, 'pages/corpuschristi.html', context)
```

And this is my For Loop in the html page:

```
 {% for service in services %}
   <div class="col s12 m6">
     <li class="service"> {{ service.name }} </li>
   </div>  
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you render the correct template. If you write something *outside* the loop, is it rendered in the result?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the page renders fine. There's just a sad void of info where the ForLoop is supposed to be displaying data.

Comment: Do you want to add `{% debug %}` tag in top of your template and double check the variables?

Comment: yes, the variables are correct.

Comment: Is that template extending another one? Maybe the for loop is supposed to be inside one of the blocks defined by the parent(s) but it's not

Comment: I tried wrapping only the li in the for-loop, if that's what you meant bug, but there was no difference in what was rendered.